# Building Android apk from kivy application

Tags: android, python, apk, kivy

I am trying to build the android app from kivy application. I used the Buildozer image as given on the kivy.org downloads page, but that Virtual Machine never runs on the virtualbox. Is there any other way to do this. I have seen some SO questions regarding this but they seem to be very old and hasn't been of much help till now.

Comment: which OS are you using? and did u set up buildozer correctly?

Comment: I have tried both on windows 8 and windows 10. I am directly trying to use the buildozer vm as given in the kivy.org downloads page but that vm never even starts. Also i tried to just install the kivy on ubuntu which i have installed on the vmware workstation but that also didnt get installed.

Comment: I never tried running Kivy on virtual machines before, I suggest you to create a dual boot and install a Linux OS, and install kivy, python to android and buildozer in that OS, Since buildozer is supported only on Linux

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide information about what goes wrong when you try to run the VM - nobody can help if we know only that something doesn't work.

Alternatively, you can make a new VM with any linux distro (a recent Ubuntu is a good choice) and install all the dependencies. Kivy's VM is nothing special except that it has them preinstalled.